# Signal conditioning of conductive polymer

Tags: sensor, signal-processing, signal-theory

I have a conductive elastic polymer which gives the resistance change of 800 Kohm with the input strain of 250%. and also gives linear response when the force is applied. I wanted to have a signal conditioning circuit which can measure the force range in the range of 0 to 45 gm. how can i start designing the signal conditioning.? Thank You.

Comment: Please provide a link to the polymer and show how you are going to make connections to it.

Comment: its CNT conductive polymer. I have attached the both end of the polymer sample to the copper electrode. It shows the creep behavior every time but gives the approximate resistance change for same strain. so far I have prepared the signal conditioning, by having the voltage divider circuit and what could be the next step after that to have the output voltage in the range of 0-5 v.

Comment: https://vb9uhg-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3m5Tk4HMsHtOW445tGFd4B8FYyu3gHTDhI9eQ_FVkx5b8mH3_W96tJfai7PoM-lb3jxbg4Ilm3mqkYN7gi3CRhd7p3PcKiyYzsJgt3oLqMSXGWWJDRdgjG-T4Fa5chTSCAmwY6fpzTa8tH04s87W1qQe19QRKmyP3m8-Wvelic62Y?width=592&height=437&cropmode=none

Comment: https://sr9uhg-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3mVxMgBZfx2vlDJsCo6GcU9xZKd9dYyHoogZT2SIiB7Vb90PmDldW8ze8Kzu0v8QlcNCs9Nfd_ruRCpHbucrtB4qzJ_3hEiI11ZWsquoTJRhfabjpjJ6W4LVfyjaIs_d1-pT0hQSgMQoHOiq5fL1hsYAl1nnMntYytBF901XAzUzk?width=491&height=192&cropmode=none

Comment: @Andyaka I have provide the link of the sensor and its behavior. I wanted to have the signal conditioning  circuit which gives the voltage output in the range of 0 to 5 volts regards to the strain input of 25 %.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=371B2D9E3A748E90&resid=371B2D9E3A748E90%211647&authkey=AEyMSkPPRpTWpz0

Comment: Please post links that can be read.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=371B2D9E3A748E90&resid=371B2D9E3A748E90%211648&authkey=AIMdg_GK0OAOZgE

Comment: sorry for the unreadable link.. in last comment i have attached the link which can be open in web browser

Comment: @Andyaka 
https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=371B2D9E3A748E90&resid=371B2D9E3A748E90%211648&authkey=AIMdg_GK0OAOZgE
https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=371B2D9E3A748E90&resid=371B2D9E3A748E90%211647&authkey=AEyMSkPPRpTWpz0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to use an instrumentation amplifier (TI, ADI, LT are all suppliers of such devices) and operate your polymer in a wheatstone bridge configuration with a stable excitation voltage. Here's a typical idea: -

[image]

You should also consider reading [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSkMuB2ILRAhUQO1AKHfusBcoQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fan%2Fsloa034%2Fsloa034.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG5I17YD4oDzCVjCrVnvcfFDOKZCw&sig2=6ak0ADzv94v0KoElQ1THrA&cad=rja) article

Comment: I see you have moved on from this question and answer. If this answer proved useful then please consider formally accepting it.